# How to create 4 divs side by side?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a header pane like you see at the top of the stackoverflow page, with an icon, then a page title, both aligned to the left, then two icons aligned to the right. The method I'm using (and feel free to enlighten me on a better one) is a div with 4 divs inside it. See HTML and CSS snippets below.

#### HTML

```
<div id="headerDiv">
    <div id="menuButtonDiv"><image src="resources/icons/menu.png" /></div>
    <div id="headerTitleDiv">
        <h1 style="padding-top: 6px">
            <ui:insert name="title">Default Title</ui:insert>
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div id="userButtonDiv"><image src="resources/icons/user.png" /></div>
    <div id="settingsButtonDiv"><image src="resources/icons/settings.png" /></div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#headerDiv {
    margin-left: 0.5%;
    background-color: #00467e;
    color: white;
    width: 99%
}

#menuButtonDiv {
    float: left;
    background-color: #00467e;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}

#userButtonDiv {
    float: right;
    background-color: #00467e;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}

#settingsButtonDiv {
    float: right;
    background-color: #00467e;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}

#headerTitleDiv {
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #00467e;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 75px;
}
```

However, for some reason, the two buttons on the right are wrapping into a new line. See the below image:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To float them right, just change the order of the elements. Floated elements always goes before an element without flout

```
<div id="headerDiv">
    <div id="menuButtonDiv"><image src="resources/icons/menu.png" /></div>
    <div id="userButtonDiv"><image src="resources/icons/user.png" /></div>
    <div id="settingsButtonDiv"><image src="resources/icons/settings.png" /></div>
    <div id="headerTitleDiv">
        <h1 style="padding-top: 6px">
            <ui:insert name="title">Default Title</ui:insert>
        </h1>
    </div>        
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That worked perfectly. Any idea how to vertically center the three-dot icon in the div?

Comment: add "padding-top: 10px;  box-sizing: border-box;" to #settingsButtonDiv. 10 is for example, try different digits.

Comment: And, by the way, there is no such tag as <image ... />. Correct is <img ... />

Comment: Lots of duplicates of this in stackiverflow or results in  search engines